# How to set image as background for all Android devices so that stretching does not distort it?

Tags: android, nine-patch

[image]

Reference the image attached. How to set such an image as background?
Does using 9-patch makes it possible?

Comment: as pankaj said above yes its possible and don't forget to put that image recourse in a drawable-nodpi folder

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Please Use 9-Patch image and Please check **[this](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/tools/help/draw9patch.html)** on how to draw 9-patch image and also this **[Video Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQRA9nwxU7g)**

Comment: i don't think that you can use 9 patch drawable in that case because of repeating pattern

Answer (score 0):

Refer to your ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, and xxhdpi folders there you will have to format your image to fit the particular sizes of each screen. Another way of doing it would be android:setbackground="@drawable:example"; in your xml and testing your app out in the emulator on all the different screen sizes to see if it really matters that much due to the simplicity of your image.

It would be much simpler to create a high res .png file in your case. and might end up working better (just a thought)

Answer (score 0):

If attached image is the only case, then you could try and create your own drawable by extending Drawable class.

It's just a rectangle with circles cutout on each side. This can be easily drawn using drawRect and drawCircle. This way you'll get perfect quality on every screen.